# beforeunload event and JQuery Dialog immediately closes after switch screen

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Good day, 
Here is the structure of my .php
Main.php

```
 All of the navibar is here.
 There's an Iframe screen also from my contents.
```

Content1.php

```
 My content 1 contains textfields.
 Jquery dialog if you are leaving the screens.
```

Content1 code :

```
 $(window).bind('beforeunload', function(e){
      dialog();
 });
```

dialog();

```
 $('form[name="rowform"]').on('submit', function (e) {
         e.preventDefault();
     });

     var fieldNamesToCheck = xxxxx;
     var previousValueFieldNames = xxxxx;

     if (detectChangesOnInputs(fieldNamesToCheck, previousValueFieldNames)) {
        $("#unsaved-values-confirmation-dialog").dialog("open");
        $('.ui-dialog :button').blur();
    }
```

for the close and refresh event, the beforeunload event does fine.
but when I start hitting my navibar,
what happen is, the dialog shows and immediately closes.

is there any wrong in my codes? thanks!

Comment: can toggle a flag that determines if dialog shown or not

Comment: I'm not sure I get it, but you can't show a custom dialog on unload, and expect it to halt the closing/redirect in any way, only the native popup will do that ?

Comment: @adeneo, actually, that code did it. the prolem is, since the conten1 is on iframe, and I am accessing the main.php, it means, the content1 closes that's why the dialog closes also immediately (that's my assumption).